# Check if props contain string or SVG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I pass props to a component that can be either string or an SVG. I want to render it conditionally based on the type.

This is what I tried:

```js
const ProjectIcon = ({icon}) => { // icon can be an SVG or just a string string
  console.log("string: "+icon);
  console.log(typeof icon === "string"); // true for both string AND SVG
  console.log(typeof icon !== "string"); // false for both string AND SVG
  return (...) // return based on the type of props
}
```

I import an SVG file or set a string variable in a distant parent component:

`Parent.jsx`

```
import svg from "./icon.svg";
import Parent from "./Parent.jsx";

const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <ProjectIcon icon={svg}>
  )
}
```

I import this `icon.svg`

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" width="100%">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
</svg>
```

It seems like both types are interptreted like a string. How can I tell the difference in JavaScript / React?

Comment: What does it mean "it can be an SVG", in React it means it can be a `ReactComponent`, does it happen in your case? Please provide a producible example. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript treats the XML definition from the SVG file like a string. I came up with this solution which worked fine for my use case:

```js
const ProjectIcon = ({icon}) => { 
  // icon can be an SVG file or a string of characters I want to display

  if (icon.substring(0, 14) !== "data:image/svg") {
    return (
      // handle SVG
    );
  }
  return (
    // handle string
  );
}
```

Note that This does not work for text that starts with "data:image/svg".

Answer (score 1):

If your imported svg comes as a string you could parse it back into an object and check the type.

```
const icon1 = <svg...>...</svg>
const icon2 = 'some string'
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(icon1)).type==='svg'// is true
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(icon2)).type==='svg'// is false
```

Otherwise an svg is just an object and `typeof icon` should give object or string accordingly. One could also check for the length which should be `undefined` for a svg. Check out the snippet below. The circle background color is blue for string and red for svg's.

```js
function Tile(){
  const SVG = <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="grey">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" /></svg>
  return <div>
  <div className='tile'><Circle icon={SVG}/></div>
  <div className='tile'><Circle icon='test'/></div>
  </div>
}
function Circle({icon}){
  return <div style={{background: icon.length?'blue':'red'}} className='circle'>{icon}</div>
}
ReactDOM.render(<Tile/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.tile{ position: relative; display: inline-block; margin-left: 10px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: orange; }
.circle{ position: absolute; top: 25px; left: 25px; width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50%; line-height: 50px; text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; }
```

```html
<div id='root'></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```